# Resharper test runner throw a TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, resharper

When I try to launch my unit tests, a error windows appears :

```
System.TypeLoadException: Method 'get_SolutionDirectory' 
in type 'JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestRunner.MSTest.RunContext' ... 
does not have an implementation.
```

The ReSharper version is : 7.0.1098.2760

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Version 7.0.1098.2760

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For everyone after me, I changed the Framework of test from

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
```

To

```
nunit.framework
```

And it works fine.

Good Luck for all!

Comment: Hum, sorry but I can tell as it was my question that this workaround works well.

In addition I think this is a better framework, more wildely used.

Still I value the fact that you explain this -1, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

It is a well know problem in resharpr 7.0: (you could look at discussion on [jetbrains forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/439469))
The easiest way is to upgrade resharper to newer version (7.1.3 is the latest 7.x version). It is a free upgrade

Comment: Thank you Garath, I found a workaround.
It can still help the next dev!

Comment: How can implementing a different TestFramework be a workaround?

Comment: @THomas True, but how can Using a different testFranework be a workaround for a tool that for some reason does not run the tests? Sounds like this Resharper feature (on a specific version) is preferred over a good decision for a TestFramework.

Comment: @MauriceStam This is very surprising, but I am pragmatic, it is working now. I don't know why or pretend that it is logic. I work in a place with security proxy, so updating resharper is not an option for me.